# Keeping Track of Dynamic UIViews - Best Practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

So lets say I have 4 UIViews.

Each UIView has been created and added to the main view dynamically from backend data.

I have a model.  This model contains an array of 4 objects, each object is the same.

We have a UIView for each object in the array of my model.

When a UIView is tapped, a point is deducted.

What is the best practice for 'binding' the UIView to the correct object so that I know which object to deduct the points from?

Tags perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use tags, but they're not really meant for that. You're better off putting the views into an array and using that as an index. It'll be a lot more flexible. You could also subclass `UIView` and add your own index property. This is probably the best choice in your case. Either way is better than using a tag.

Imagine down the line that you have to change the tags. When you change one tag, you'll probably have to change them all. It becomes a big mess rather quickly.

[Here's a link](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html) as an attempt to further convince you not to use tags for this purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Give each `UIView` a tag from 1-4 when they are created and then use

```
object = [array objectAtIndex:view.tag-1];
```

to retrieve the correct object

Comment: You can use minus numbers too

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIView and add a @property for the model, then set the model when creating each view? I know this couples the UIView to the model, but it does seem a lot more robust than using random tags to identify each one.

If you wanna go for tags is also ok, is the way u usually handle taps on UITableViewCells, grabbing the index and accesing each model in an array for that index.